# Replace single and double reversed quotes to typewriter quotes in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to single reverse `‛` and double `‟` reversed quote in PHP using `str_replace` method but its not getting replaced. I tried to convert it using `htmlentities()` and replace it using their html values but its not also working.

Here's the code:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$text = str_replace("&#8219;", "'", $text);
```

2nd attempt:

```
$text = str_replace("‛", "'", $text);
```

Reference for single and double reversed quote: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eugene This should be the one. You forgot `_decode`.

`$text = str_replace(htmlspecialchars_decode("&#8219;"), "'", $text);`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`$text = str_replace(htmlspecialchars("&#8219;"), "'", $text);`